# How do I avoid this mysql deadlock?

Tags: mysql, deadlock

Sometimes, I get the following dead lock error in my app:

```
SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

The table in question looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `oauth_access_token` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `access_token` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `oauth_client_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `instance_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `expires` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_oauth_access_token_instance_idx` (`instance_id`),
  KEY `FK_oauth_access_token_oauth_client_idx` (`oauth_client_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_oauth_access_token_instance` FOREIGN KEY (`instance_id`) REFERENCES `instance` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_oauth_access_token_oauth_client` FOREIGN KEY (`oauth_client_id`) REFERENCES `oauth_client` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=248 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I have a transaction that runs these queries and I believe they cause the deadlock:

```
DELETE oauth_access_token_scope
FROM oauth_access_token_scope
INNER JOIN oauth_access_token
ON (oauth_access_token_scope.oauth_access_token_id = oauth_access_token.id)
WHERE oauth_access_token.expires <= UTC_TIMESTAMP()

DELETE FROM oauth_access_token WHERE expires <= UTC_TIMESTAMP()

DELETE oauth_jti
FROM oauth_jti
WHERE oauth_jti.expires <= UTC_TIMESTAMP()
```

If I run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`, the logged deadlock info is:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2014-02-03 10:36:45 7ffc5ded2700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3228803, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 15 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 2692, OS thread handle 0x7ffc5dcca700, query id 36603 localhost 127.0.0.1 root updating
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 20338 page no 3 n bits 88 index `PRIMARY` of table `app`.`oauth_access_token` trx id 3228803 lock_mode X waiting
*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3228804, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 15 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 2693, OS thread handle 0x7ffc5ded2700, query id 36604 localhost 127.0.0.1 root updating
DELETE FROM oauth_access_token WHERE expires <= UTC_TIMESTAMP()
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 20338 page no 3 n bits 88 index `PRIMARY` of table `app`.`oauth_access_token` trx id 3228804 lock mode S
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 20338 page no 3 n bits 88 index `PRIMARY` of table `app`.`oauth_access_token` trx id 3228804 lock_mode X waiting
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

Although I understand the theory of why deadlocks occur, I am not sure why it is occurring in this case. I think the deadlock occurs when 2 simultaneous user requests causes those statements to be executed at the same time.

Why is a deadlock occurring in this instance? What can be done (besides retrying the transaction) to make it "safe" so that deadlocks do not happen?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a join on a UPDATE/DELETE statement you issue a shared lock on the joined table, that holds it while another transaction tries to get an exclusive lock on it.

Isn't `oauth_access_token_scope.oauth_access_token_id` an indexed foreign key pointing to `oauth_access_token`? You could avoid the first `DELETE` statement by using `ON DELETE CASCADE` on it.

From your example, I don't know if `oauth_jti` has any reference to the other tables, if it does, it should be checked if a single `DELETE` statement might be used, so that the order of locks from different transactions are always the same.

Another solution, without modifying the table structure: since this deadlock might be related to concurrent user access, adding constraints to the delete query that prevent different users from modifying each other records also avoids the deadlock. For example, if you can add different `oauth_access_token.oauth_user_id` in the WHERE clause for each user then they will only lock their own rows.